# Ava testing image-loading with promise: promise returned by test never resolved

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ava

I want to test my promise function to load an image, the piece of code looks like this:

```
function imagePromise() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.addEventListener('load', () => resolve(true));
    img.addEventListener('error', () => reject(false));
    img.src = 'http://78.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lr9mx5Axur1qlyuwso1_1280.jpg';
  });
}
```

When I consume my promise in the browser, it works fine:

```
imagePromise().then((result) => console.log(result));
// fulfill the promise and log the result: true
```

However, when I'm testing my promise using [ava](https://github.com/avajs/ava) and [browser-env](https://github.com/lukechilds/browser-env), ava returns an error:

```
Promise returned by test never resolved
```

My test file looks like this:

```
import test from 'ava';

function imagePromise() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.addEventListener('load', () => resolve(true));
    img.addEventListener('error', () => reject(false));
    img.src = 'http://78.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lr9mx5Axur1qlyuwso1_1280.jpg';
  });
}

test('load image with promise', (t) => {
  return imagePromise().then((result) => {
    t.is(result, true);
  });
});
```

Note that I have both tried `addEventListener` and `onload`/`onerror` methods due to browser compatibility, and browser-env have been [configured to work with ava](https://github.com/avajs/ava/blob/master/docs/recipes/browser-testing.md#setup-browser-env). Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally fixed my tests, using `browser-env` (which itself uses `jsdom`). I've made a [small repo for people interested](https://github.com/TotomInc/ava-test-image-promise):

My first mistake was I forgot to install `canvas-prebuilt`, which allow `jsdom` to manipulate `images` and `canvas` elements.

```
// install browser-env and canvas-prebuilt
// (https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom#loading-subresources)
yarn add browser-env canvas-prebuilt -D
```

My second mistake that I forgot to put a special config on the `browser-env` declaration for the tests, in the `test/helpers/setup-browser-env.js` file:

```
require('browser-env')(['window', 'document', 'Image'], {
  resources: 'usable',
});
```

Then we can run our image-loading promises tests, from `test/test.js`:

```
import test from 'ava';

function imagePromise() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.addEventListener('load', () => resolve(true));
    img.addEventListener('error', () => reject(false));
    // an heavy 4k wallpaper to check if promise is resolved after a long time
    img.src = 'https://www.wallpaperup.com/wallpaper/download/991808/8000/5224';
  });
}

test('load image with promise', (t) => {
  return imagePromise().then((result) => {
    t.is(result, true);
  });
});
```

To run the tests, you can exec `ava` but I highly recommend to add `--verbose` flag as it helps to debug with `--watch` flag (kind of a live-reload for your tests).

Answer (score 0):

How about move image creation from `imagePromise` to `ImageClass`? After that you will have control on promise resolving / rejection

```
import test from "ava";
import { EventEmitter } from "events";

function imagePromise(img) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        img.addEventListener("load", () => resolve(true));
        img.addEventListener("error", () => reject(false));
        img.src = "http://78.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lr9mx5Axur1qlyuwso1_1280.jpg";
    });
}

test("load image with promise", t => {
    class ImageClass extends EventEmitter {
        addEventListener(type, fn) {
            this.on(type, fn);
        }
    }

    const image = new ImageClass();

    process.nextTick(() => image.emit("load"));

    return imagePromise(image).then(result => {
        t.is(result, true);
    });
});
```

Comment: I've made a rough example of how I wanted to do things, but behind this I have a loader class with sub-loaders classes (such as ImageLoader, AudioLoader, ...). But I finally managed to fix my test, I'm going to write it as an answer in a few mins. Thanks for the help.